# Retaining dropdown values after submitting form using GET method

Tags: php, html

I am using dropdown to select values, and after I click the submit button, my values change. Please help me retain the selected values. Using POST method I have got the solution, but I want to use with GET method. Is it possible?

1.) 1st select stmt:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
   <select name="sort"  >
     <option value="inc_patientName">Patient Name</option>
     <option value="inc_date">Date</option>
     <option value="inc_status">Status</option>
     <option value="inc_patientAge">Age</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="GETREPORT" value="Get Report"/>
   if ($_GET)
   {echo"hi";}
</form>
```

2.) 2nd select with while

```
<?php
    //Selecting ward from table ward master
    $sql = "SELECT ward_name,ward_id FROM ward_master";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<select name='ward'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['ward_id'] . "'>" . $row['ward_name'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

3.) 3rd select with javascript:

```
<select name="daydropdown" id="daydropdown" ></select> 
    <select name="monthdropdown" id="monthdropdown"></select>
    <select name="yeardropdown" id="yeardropdown"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield)
{
   var today=new Date()
   var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
   var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
   var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
   for (var i=1; i<=31; i++)
   dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i)
   dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
   for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
   monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
   monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
   var thisyear=1999
   for (var y=0; y<45; y++){
   yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
   thisyear+=1
   }
   yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
}    
</script>
```

Comment: use **<?php if(isset($_GET['sort']))  echo $_GET['sort'] ;?>**

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if(isset($_GET['sort'])) {
  echo $_GET['sort'];
}
```

and get selected index

```
<option value="inc_patientName" <?php if (isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == "inc_patientName") echo 'selected="seleceted"'; ?>>Patient Name</option>
```

and so on for all options values match

For 2nd dropdown:-

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['ward_id'];?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == $row['ward_id']) echo 'selected="seleceted"'; ?>><?php echo $row['ward_name'];?></option>
    <?php }
```

Comment: Thank u.. I am getting correctly for the 1st select stmt. Can u plz help me out for other 2

Comment: check my updated answer in js you need to check same value with your options

Comment: also post your question at same time what you need , so can answer at once and make question more clear

Comment: Sorry for that.. Now i am getting for the 1st two, but 3rd one is the problem.. plz help..

Comment: Is this code in same php file? get your js options and add a compare value and use .selected

Comment: seems a new assignment for us in the cool morning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103148/how-to-retain-the-selected-values-from-date-drop-down-after-submitting-using-met :)

Comment: Yes all that codes are in same php file.                                               where to compare? sorry i dint get you.. can you please explain it clearly

Comment: in the for loop you need to compare your value for selected if(value == your option value) then use js selected for this

Comment: I am trying with that. but not getting :(

Comment: if founding typical you can use php for that looks like more complex code. there is more date time function to do that

Answer (score 1):

use it like this... it myt work.

```
<select name="ward">
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT ward_name,ward_id FROM ward_master";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        if ($_GET['ward']==$row["ward_id"]) {
           echo '<option selected="selected" value='.$row["ward_id"].'>'.$row["ward_name"].'</option>';
        } else {
           echo '<option value='.$row["ward_id"].'>'.$row["ward_name"].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<select name="sort"  >
        <option value="inc_patientName"<?php if ($_GET['sort'] == 'inc_patientName') echo ' selected="seleceted"'; ?>>Patient Name</option>
        <option value="inc_date"<?php if ($_GET['sort'] == 'inc_date') echo ' selected="seleceted"'; ?>>Date</option>
        <option value="inc_status" <?php if ($_GET['sort'] == 'inc_status') echo ' selected="seleceted"'; ?>>Status</option>
        <option value="inc_patientAge"<?php if ($_GET['sort'] == 'inc_patientAge') echo ' selected="seleceted"'; ?>>Age</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Use this function in ur script:

```
function setday(id,elementname)
{
document.getElementById(elementname).value=id;
}
```

Use this in ur php form, Repeat the same code for year and month dropdowns:

```
if (isset($_GET['daydropdown']))
            {
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>setday('".$_GET['daydropdown']."','daydropdown')</script>";
            }
```